# tableview opens different views depending on what row is clicked

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Im currently creating an app with tableview now what i like to happen is when i click the first row it will show view1 and when i click the 2nd row it will show view2. How can i do this?

i tried to use an if else statement id my  `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but it did not work here is my piece of code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

int EntryIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition:[indexPath length]-1];

{
    AboutViewController *aboutView = [[AboutViewController alloc]init];
    aboutView.getId4 = [[contentArray objectAtIndex:EntryIndex]objectForKey:@"title"];
    aboutView.aboutofficeId = getId3;
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:aboutView animated:YES];
}
else
{
    DepartmentsViewController *deptView = [[DepartmentsViewController alloc]init];
    deptView.getId5 = [[contentArray objectAtIndex:EntryIndex]objectForKey:@"title"];
    deptView.deptoffice = getId3;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:deptView animated:YES];
}

}
```

Comment: u wnt to add UIView or UIViewController>>

Comment: i want to add a new UIViewController :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE : You want to create and display UIView, so i putted here `UIView` Not    `UIViewController`.**

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        if(indexPath.row == 1)
        {
            UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake("AsYouWnat")];
            view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            [self.view addSubview:view1];
        }
        else if(indexPath.row  == 2)
        {
            UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake("AsYouWnat")];
            view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            [self.view addSubview:view2];
        }
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        ////////// As Your Row In Table
        else
        {
            UIView *viewN = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake("AsYouWnat")];
            viewN.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            [self.view addSubview:viewN];
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you show me how i can display different UIViewcontrollers?

Comment: simple create ur ViewController instand of UIView. :) such like AboutViewController *aboutView = [[AboutViewController alloc]init];
    aboutView.getId4 = [[contentArray objectAtIndex:EntryIndex]objectForKey:@"title"];
    aboutView.aboutofficeId = getId3;
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:aboutView animated:YES];

Comment: Thanks! This will do for now :)

Answer (score 0):

1. if you wish to show views You can declare an Mutable array and add UIviews in that if the UIview content have different kind of content style.
2. If you need to show view of same style but only content varies.You can look up for following code.

   ```
   UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];
   switch (indexPath.row) {
   case 0:
   { 
   //Add your label,image,etc  
   [self.view addSubview:view];
   }
       break;

       case 1:
   {

   //Add your label,image,etc  
   [self.view addSubview:view];

   }
       break;
   ```
3. If you want to show different ViewControllers then u need to do following code

   ```
   #import "ViewController1.h"
   #import "ViewController2.h"
   #import "ViewController3.h"

   -(void)viewDidLoad
   {

    VCArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:ViewController1,ViewController2,ViewController3];//allocate and init ViewController and add that to VCArray

    }



   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {

    UIViewController *viewcontr=[VCArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
    viewcontr=[[viewcontr alloc]init];
    [self presentModalViewController:viewcontr animated:YES];

     }
   ```

Comment: thanks! Im using your no.3 answer but im getting an error 

    [__NSCFConstantString parentViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ab7c

Comment: thanks! Im using your no.3 answer but im getting an error [__NSCFConstantString parentViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ab7c

Comment: @Tbt-lionArmanCapistrano can u provide the code how you added Viewcontrollers to array

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    VCArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"AboutViewController",@"DepartmentsViewController", nil];
    if ([contentArray count]==0)
    {
        [self grabXML];
        [contentTable reloadData];
    }

}

Comment: I got this error: [__NSCFConstantString alloc]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1bd2c'

Comment: @Tbt-lionArmanCapistrano Sorry my fault... at VCArray allocation remove @"" in each object and add just ViewController1,ViewController2..  Check my new edit